# PHP porque $_SESSION[nome] - sem aspas - é aceito e não dá erro em INSERT e ao destruir as sessions dá erro em unset($_SESSION[nome]

Tags: php

Recupero as informações do formulário com `foreach`

```
 foreach($_POST as $chave=>$valor){
    $_SESSION[$chave] = $conexao-> real_escape_string($valor);
 }
```

o que produz

```
 $_SESSION[nome] 
 SESSION[sobrenome] 
 etc......
```

e faço `INSERT` dessa forma **sem retornar qualquer tipo de erro**

```
 VALUES(
       '$_SESSION[nome]',
       '$_SESSION[sobrenome]',
       ...............

  $confirma = $conexao->query....
```

Porém ao destruir as sessions da forma a seguir

```
  if($confirma){
   unset($_SESSION[nome],
         $_SESSION[sobrenome],
         ..............
```

me retorna vários erros, um para cada session, como por exemplo

```
PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant nome - assumed 'nome' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION` é uma lista que recebe (neste caso) uma String como "parâmetro" (o que na verdade é o nome do index), não são as aspas e sim "o que" você coloca ali.

No primeir caso `$chave` é uma variável do tipo String, então não precisa das aspas.

No segundo:

```
VALUES(
       '$_SESSION[nome]',
       '$_SESSION[sobrenome]',
       ...............
```

Apesar de não ter colocado o código completo, sabemos que querys são Strings, logo, tudo isso que escreveu já esta entre aspas, então o compilador entende que ali são Strings então sem erros.

No terceiro o erro acontece por não ser um String, e adaptando a este contexto, não está dentro de uma String (como no segundo caso), logo ele não aceita o tipo passado, que no caso, por não ter o `$` é considera uma constante que não foi declarada.

Answer (score 1):

Vou ser o mais direto possível ao problema. Se você tem:

```
$x = "nome";
```

E faz:

```
$_SESSION[$x] = "Rui";
```

Então corresponde a fazer :

```
$_SESSION["nome"] = "Rui";
```

Repare que aqui o nome saiu com aspas porque é uma string, que era o conteúdo da variável `$x`. Isto é diferente de fazer:

```
$_SESSION[nome] = "Rui";
```

Neste último caso o interpretador não consegue perceber o que é o `nome` e assume que é uma constante não definida, mostrando o tal aviso que vê na página.